# ROR: How to make Devise logout link an image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to make my logout link in my navbar an image.

Devise provides the following:

```
<%= link_to "Logout", main_app.destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
```

Does anyone know how to get an image in here instead of text?

Tried this, doesn't work

```
<%= image_tag "logout.svg", link_to "Logout", main_app.destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => "exitLogo show-for-large" %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to pass the image as the first parameter to `link` method:

```
<%= link_to raw(image_tag('logout.svg')), main_app.destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: 'navbar-link' %>
```

You need to use `raw` method because otherwise rails will escape your HTML image tag.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the image to the content block of the link:

```
<%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, :method => 'delete' do %>
  <%= image_tag("logout.svg") %>
<% end %>
```

This will generate an HTML like:

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">
  <img src="/assets/logo-bfe14e7e4d9408d6028.svg" alt="Logo">
</a>
```

Comment: you'll just see "image_tag" in the html

Comment: you're right @Ven missed the ERB output in the original answer